# How do I use Ogre with CodeBlocks?

Tags: ogre

I want to start writing games using ogre in combination with the CodeBlocks compiler but am struggling with the installation. I got the latest version of the compiler as well as the ogre engine from their respective websites. I have installed the compiler but cannot find my way in the integration of ogre though I read their installation guide, which I found confusing.I need clear step by step guide please.

Comment: So you did compile ogre, but you cant integrate it into your project?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Codeblocks) is a step by step installation guide

Comment: From this link I can see that I'll have to make use of VC++ compiler, right?Thx 4 the link anyway

Comment: Thx man I can see now!